# Symfony 4.4 User checker on login process not triggered

Tags: symfony

I am implementing user registration process on Symfony 4.4 (without bundle) and I am stuck at the last step.

So far, this is what I have done:

1. Registration form is created
2. When user submit registration form he is well added to the database. A field activation token in user entity is fullfill.
3. An email with the activation token as parameter is automatically send to the user to activate his account
4. If the user click on the link, activation token field is set to 'null' in the user entity
5. In a user checker I check if the activation token is null
6. If activation token is not null I need to refuse the login and redirect the user to homepage with a flash message :I am stuck on this part, my User checker is not triggered. User can login with token not null.

Here is my user checker:

```
namespace App\Security;

use App\Exception\AccountDeletedException;
use App\Security\User as AppUser;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccountExpiredException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserCheckerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\DisabledException;

class UserChecker implements UserCheckerInterface
{
    public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof AppUser) {
            return;
        }

        // User account is not validated

        if ($user->getValidationToken() !== null) {
            throw  new DisabledException('User account is not activated');
        }
    }

    public function checkPostAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof AppUser) {
            return;
        }

        // user account is expired, the user may be notified
        if ($user->isExpired()) {
            throw new AccountExpiredException('...');
        }
    }
}
```

Security.yalm:

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: lazy
            provider: app_user_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\AppCustomAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout

            user_checker: App\Security\UserChecker
```

Comment: And what's your question? What have you tried to debug your problem?

Comment: My question is what is wrong or missing to have the User Checker triggered ? How can I debug this since this not related to an error but the fact that the code do not enter in the user checker exit ? Thank you

Comment: For people interested , I just removed the following part of the example code given on Symfony documentation to have it works: `if (!$user instanceof AppUser) {
            return;
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
use App\Security\User as AppUser
```

To

```
use App\Entity\User as AppUser;
```

(or whatever namespace you have on your User class)

Side note : on preAuth, you can check for the presence of the token and not if valid or not since the auth is not passed... this should be done on real Authentification, or post it...